# How to correctly use types in universal function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with typescript when i use my universal function

```
export const createNewArray = <T>(
    arr: T[],
    keyId: keyof T,
    keyTitle: keyof T,
) : [] | TValue[] => {

    const arrayAfterMap = arr.map((item) => ({name: item[keyTitle], id: item[keyId]}));
    
    if(arrayAfterMap.every(item => (typeof item?.id === "string" || typeof item?.id === "number" ) && (typeof item?.name === "string"))) {
        console.log(arrayAfterMap);
        return arrayAfterMap
    }

    return []

};
```

This function takes array and return new array. Just zero array or array with objects TValue

```
export  type TValue = {
    name: string
    id: string | number
}
```

but i get typescript error - TS2322 .

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: T[keyof T]; id: T[keyof T]; }[]' is not assignable to type '[] | TValue[]'.   
Type '{ name: T[keyof T]; id: T[keyof T]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'TValue[]'.     
Type '{ name: T[keyof T]; id: T[keyof T]; }' is not assignable to type 'TValue'.       
Types of property 'name' are incompatible.         
Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string'.           
Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.             
Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

In string - " return arrayAfterMap "

I can`t understand what i do wrong. I made a check for compliance with TValue. if the check passed, then I return the array after map , and if not, then empty. But it is not work. I will happy any advice!

And I made a test application on codesandbox so that you can see the code live. But codesandbox doesn't display this error right away - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shadow-4neth8?file=/src/constants.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this might be a type guard:

```
const isTValueArray = (arr: any[]): arr is TValue[] => arr.every(item => 
  (typeof item?.id === "string" 
    || typeof item?.id === "number" ) 
    && (typeof item?.name === "string")
  )
```

After invoking the function you can return `arrayAfterMap` with the correct type:

```
if(isTValueArray(arrayAfterMap)) {
  return arrayAfterMap
}
```

---

A more complex approach would be to add two more generic types for each key to the function:

```
export const createNewArray = <
  T extends {[keyId in KeyId]: string}  // T[KeyId] should be string
    & {[keyTitle in KeyTitle]: string | number},
  KeyId extends keyof T, 
  KeyTitle extends keyof T>(
    arr: T[],
    keyId: KeyId,
    keyTitle: KeyTitle,
) : TValue[] => {

    const arrayAfterMap = arr.map((item) => ({name: item[keyTitle], id: item[keyId]}));
    
    return arrayAfterMap
};
```

Here TypeScript will automatically know that `arrayAfterMap` is equivalent to `TValue[]`.

Comment: Wow. i am trying understand and first and second variant. And this is hard for me yet.)) But it is working and this very good. Thank for you help!